# pandas - histogram from two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

I have this data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame().from_dict([r for r in response])
print data

     _id  total
0    213      1
1    194      3
2    205      156
...
```

Now, if I call:

```
data.hist()
```

I will get two separate histograms, one for each column. This is not what I want. What I want is a single histogram made using those two columns, where one column is interpreted as a value and another one as a number of occurrences of this value. What should I do to generate such a histogram?

I tried:

```
data.hist(column="_id", by="total")
```

But this generates even more (empty) histograms with error message.

Comment: did you try this from the examples: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histograms_chart.html it uses bokeh, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always drop to the lower-level [`matplotlib.hist`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import hist
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '_id': np.random.randn(100),
    'total': 100 * np.random.rand()
})
hist(df._id, weights=df.total)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Since you already have the bin frequencies computed (the `total` column), just use `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```
data.plot( x='_id', y='total', kind='hist')
```