# Histogram of one field wrt another in pandas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram distribution of one column with respect to another. For example, if the dataframe columns are ['count','age'], then I want to plot the total counts in each age group. Suppose in

> age: 0-10 -> total count was 20
>
> age: 10-20 -> total count was 10
>
> age: 20-30 -> ... etc

I tried `groupby('age')` and than plotting histogram but it didn't work.

Thanks.

### Update

Here is some of my data

```
df.head()
   age    count
0   65  2417.86
1   65  4173.50
2   65  3549.16
3   65   509.07
4   65     0.00
```

Also,  `df.plot( x='age', y='count', kind='hist')` shows

[image: degree/count histogram plot]

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571830/pandas-histogram-from-two-columns/31571945#31571945). ```dataframe.plot( x='age', y='count', kind='hist')``` (if it works, add a vote to my answer in that link :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply but it didn't work, it is still showing wrt number of element. They y axis is correct my x -axis is not 'age'

Comment: why not paste dataframe.head() into your post for more help?

Comment: Could you rephrase "Now i want to check out how much in each age group i have how many counts". It doesn't really make sense. Do you want to add all the values in `count` column for each age or get the number of values for each age?

Comment: Suppose my age range is 0-100, I would like to check the sum of all counts who falls under one bin of age (ex. 20-30, 30-40 etc). I am sorry if it still doesn't make sense. In case of df.head(). All the counts should be binned in one range which would be (60-70) if you are binsize is 10.

Comment: Consider my edit, might help you get more responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,if I understand correctly, you want a weighted histogram

```
import pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
np = pd.np

df = pd.DataFrame( {'age':np.random.normal( 50,10,300).astype(int),
                    'counts':1000*np.random.random(300)} ) # test data
#df.head()
#   age      counts
#0   38  797.174450
#1   36  402.171434
#2   49  894.218420
#3   66  841.786623
#4   51  597.040259

df.hist('age',weights=df['counts'] )
plt.ylabel('counts')
plt.show()
```

yields the figure[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Now if i want to get average in each bin instead of sum of counts, how would i go about it.