# Type issue with histogram plot python

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, timedelta

I've some data as:

```
t1['Time Delay']
Out[175]: 
746     0 days
747     0 days
873     0 days
874     0 days
906     8 days
907     0 days
908     0 days
909     0 days
Name: Time Delay, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

And another column as:

```
t1['Outcome']
Out[176]: 
746     0.0
747     0.0
758     0.0
762     0.0
1422    1.0
1685    0.0
1909    0.0
1913    0.0
Name: Outcome, dtype: float64
```

I'm trying to plot them as histograms based on this [pandas - histogram from two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571830/pandas-histogram-from-two-columns) but a bunch of type issues are coming up.

If I check `type(t1['Time Delay'])`, it gives `pandas.core.series.Series`. Same for the other column.

Do I need to convert the timedelta to float?

Comment: I would do `ans = t1.dt.days` and plot that variable

Comment: @Yuca: That's what I ended up doing after much research :)

Comment: glad to hear, happy coding!